# Referencing sheets in another workbook by codename using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to copy data from one workbook to my current workbook using VBA. *InputBook* is a workbook object referring to the file from which I would like to extract data. The main issue has to do with referencing particular worksheets in the *InputBook* workbook. In *InputBook*, I have a worksheet named *"Lines"* with the codename *LINES*. I would prefer to reference this worksheet by its codename, for example:

```
NumItems = WorksheetFunction.CountA(InputBook.LINES.Columns(1))
```

This clearly doesn't work and I know I can make it function by using either of the following:

```
NumItems = WorksheetFunction.CountA(InputBook.Sheets("Lines").Columns(1))
NumItems = WorksheetFunction.CountA(InputBook.Sheets(2).Columns(1))
```

I would, however, rather not use either of those methods as they seem to be less robust. Is there any way to reference the codename of a worksheet object in another open workbook? Thanks.

Comment: does `NumItems = WorksheetFunction.CountA(LINES.Columns(1))` work?  It should if you have it defined as `set LINES = InputBook.Sheets("Lines")`

Comment: I haven't defined LINES anywhere in the code; it was only set manually, permanently as the codename for that particular worksheet. I want to avoid altogether having to define it as a function of the worksheet name.

Comment: Late answer, but I posted on this: http://yoursumbuddy.com/using-worksheet-codenames-in-other-workbooks/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can "hack" a reference to another workbook sheet code name by:

```
Sub UseCodeNameFromOutsideProject()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    With Workbooks("InputBook .xls")
        Set WS = _
            .Worksheets(CStr(.VBProject.VBComponents("Lines").Properties(7)))
        debug.print WS.Name
    End With
 End Sub
```

Your `WS` object is now set to the sheet which has the codename "Lines" in this example.

---

Original inspiration is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!msg/microsoft.public.excel.programming/6dKW81xp5KA/gGjz9PoKKEoJ).

Comment: and what the benefit of your approach? why it's better than `Set Ws=InputBook.Sheets("Lines")`?

Comment: @simoco if the user changes the sheet name (not CodeName) to be say, "my Lines" the code you wrote will break. Referencing the `CodeName` means the only time it will not work is if someone edits the `CodeName` in the VBA IDE. It's almost always advantageous to reference `CodeName` rather than the Sheet name for this reason.

Comment: +1 you're right, actually I misundersood the question when read it first time:)

Comment: This is a clever fix to the issue BUT only works if the computer running the code has "Trust access to the VBA project object model" set to true in the users Macro Settings. Most end users have this set to false.

Answer (score 0):

I could call a workbook "I LIKE TEA" but `InputBook.I LIKE TEA.Columns(1)` wont cut it.

Abstract the name away with a `const` or:

```
public enum InputSheets
   LINES = 2,
   GARMENTS = 4
end enum
```

to allow:

```
InputBook.Sheets(InputSheets.LINES).Columns(1)
```

or

```
MyGetSheetFunction(InputBook, InputSheets.LINES)
```

You could take this further and use a wrapper class.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I were to use this method, then I will have to be concerned about the sheet order in the InputBook file, right? Unfortunately I can't be sure that it will remain in place. I am trying to avoid any dependence on sheet location or sheet name and am looking to link directly to the codename. Is there no support for this type of operation?

Comment: Name and position are the only two identifying factors.  You could iterate all the sheets looking for some unique bit of data in a cell.

Comment: OK, that's fine. I hoped the codename was accessible but an iterative search will be a reasonable work-around. Thanks for all your help.