# Using Worksheet CodeName and Avoiding .Select & .Activate

Tags: vba, excel, select, reference

In my workbook I frequently need to activate some sheets by using their **CodeName** then **search for some texts** within that sheet and **use the row or column number of the cell** that contains the text I'm looking for.

In that situations, I am using below kind of codes:

```
Sheet16.Select '(Using codename)
Cells.Find(What:="FIRST TEXT I'M LOOKING FOR", After:= _
        ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

   FirstRow= ActiveCell.Row

    Cells.Find(What:="SECOND TEXT I'M LOOKING FOR", After:= _
        ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

SecondRow = ActiveCell.Row

Rows(FirstRow & ":" & SecondRow + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

Eveything works well, but nowadays I am trying to improve my codes and I'd like to run my codes faster.

***Now,***

### 1- How can I reference my WorkSheets' CodeName easily?

**(I'm looking for answer like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") - not a function**

```
Dim wb as Workbook, ws as Worksheet
set wb = ThisWorkbook
set ws = wb.CodeName(Sheet16) or wb.Sheet16 or sheet16
'then 
ws.Cells.Find(What ..........   rest of the code  ...... )
```

none of them working for **`CodeName`** property.
[Fully reference a worksheet by codename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203173/fully-reference-a-worksheet-by-codename) or [Referencing sheets in another workbook by codename using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256536/referencing-sheets-in-another-workbook-by-codename-using-vba) didn't answer my question.

### 2- How can I avoid using **.Activate** to use the result cell of **Cells.Find()** formula.

Again in that example I firstly search for specific text, which is **:="FIRST TEXT I'M LOOKING FOR"** in the first part of my code, and then I need to use that cell to get it's **row number** or use **offset** or **anything** , and because of that I feel myself obligated to use **.Activate** because,

```
FirstRow =  Cells.Find(What:="FIRST TEXT I'M LOOKING FOR", After:= _
        ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
```

kind of codes do not work as well. [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/7130016) here in that answer there are couple of suggestions but none of them helps me in this case. I tried to get an answer from the owner of this answer to avoid any duplicate question but he suggested me to ask a new question. *(And as long as both of my questions belong to my example code and I'll connect them, I asked them together in one question.)*

Comment: 1. Why not a function? They're works well. Another option here: You can add a dictionary as member of `ThisWorkbook` and populate it with (ws.CodeName, ws) pair on events such as Open, NewSheet and at cetera. And after that you can pull your ws from that dict just with `Set ws =ThisWorkbook.CodeNameWss("Codename")`. 2.Best option to avoid an `Activate` - just not using it. Don't feel obligated to use it, if you need anything except "activating" the cell.

Comment: @sktneer Thank you. This sentence is from SO  help center to explain us **When should we vote down?** ==> **Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.** I am trying to solve this issue for a very long time and as I mentioned within the text, I really spent a lot of effort searched for many sources and I think it's not that *egregiously sloppy* and I wonder where is not clear enough..

Comment: @CommonSense thanks for your interest. Because I use this kind of codes a lot and I don't want to run another function each time. But the question is answered now, the only thing I was missing is, CodeNames are only working in ThisWorkbook so when I was trying to define it one more time, it was occurring an error.

Comment: @Mertinc, CodeName is a string property and you trying to use a hard-coded variable (in scope of thisworkbook), If your codenames are changed over time (and you doesnt handle it) - your code will fail, but with function approach there're less pain if it happen. Your question is misleading, because you never really use a codename. It's better to run a function each time than use a hard-coded stuff. But if you sufficent with that - who am I to blame you (:

Comment: Oh no mate cheers thanks for your interest :) But I think you misunderstood me, my CodeNames will never change unless I want it. (I'm not talking about Sheet Names , which user can easily change. Actually the reason I'm using CodeNames is to avoid this problem.) And I really do use a codename :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While setting a sheet variable to the codename, the limitation is you can use the codename in ThisWorkbook only i.e. the workbook which contains the code.

Consider this code...

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wsData 'where wsData is the CodeName of a sheet.
```

Now in your code you can manipulate or perform actions on ws sheet without activating or selecting it.
Actually in case of CodeNames, you don't need to declare a sheet variable, you can directly refer to the sheet by using it's codename irrespective of which sheet is currently active.

like...

```
wsData.Cells.Clear
Set Rng = wsData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

e.g. with your another example code

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wsData 'where wsData is the CodeName of a sheet.

FirstRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="FIRST TEXT I'M LOOKING FOR", After:= _
        ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

'Or just (without declaring the ws sheet variable where wsData is the sheet code name)
FirstRow = wsData.Cells.Find(What:="FIRST TEXT I'M LOOKING FOR", After:= _
        ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
```

Comment: Oh, so the only thing I was missing: **the limitation is you can use the codename in ThisWorkbook only** information in this case. Anyway, that's solved now. But can you please underline that `wsData` **is not a variable** but really just Worksheet's **CodeName**. (I misunderstood it at first) Thanks @sktneer

Comment: @Mertinc You're welcome. Glad you found it useful. I have added the comment in the solution to make is clear that wsData is the sheet code name.